# confidence intervals for dependent observations

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, p-value, independence

[The answer to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61266/why-is-dependence-a-problem) discusses problems associated with calculating P-values for dependent observations. Let's say you have observations from two different groups that are dependent. You consider carrying out a t-test to compare means of the two groups. However, aware that the calculated P-values in a t-test will likely be inaccurate, you calculate means of each group and their 95% confidence intervals. Does calculating confidence intervals avoid problems associated with calculating P-values when observations are dependent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Since confidence intervals convey the same inferential information as $p$-values ($\mu_0 \in \mathrm{CI} \iff p_{H_0:\mu_0=\mu}\geq \alpha$), they also share the same difficulties dealing with dependence.