# Resources to understand why dependence is a problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, standard-error, independence

For many statistical procedures, it seems the observations must be independent. For example the observations within each group in a two-sample t-test must be independent for the standard error/P-value to be accurately computed. Likewise, the observations of an independent variable in linear regression must also be independent. But I cannot understand why dependence will cause incorrect standard error/P-values. [I've this question before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61266/12492) and unfortunately didn't understand the answer. This time round I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of resources that clearly explain why dependence a problem and that also demonstrate it being a problem. Are there any books/videos/PDFs/blog posts out there that achieve this? I'm particularly interested in resources that visualise why dependence a problem.

Comment: The OP already explained why "those answers do not fully address his question" and asked a distinctly different question here (asking for resources, for example). How did this question fail to do already what the closure text suggests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I cannot understand why dependence will cause incorrect standard error/P-values

Consider the simplest case - a one sample t-test.

Basic fact: Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y)

So when Cov(X,Y) > 0 we have Var(X+Y) > Var(X) + Var(Y)

and  when Cov(X,Y) < 0 we have Var(X+Y) < Var(X) + Var(Y)

As a result, Var($\bar{X}$) will either be over or under estimated depending on whether
$\sum_{X\neq Y}$ Cov(X,Y) > 0 or < 0.

So then the standard error of the sample mean would be larger (or smaller) than is assumed by the t-test, and so the numerator of the t-statistic will be correspondingly larger (or smaller) relative the the denominator which assumes independence -- and as a result, p-values will be too small or too large compared to what they would be if the covariance was correctly specified.

Similar things happen with regression and ANOVA.

Let's consider one form of dependence in our variates in the one-sample t-test - serial correlation. I simulated thousands of one-sample t-tests for both independent data (the actual assumption for the test) and serially correlated data ($\rho(X_t,X_{t-1})=0.9$).

The simulated t-statistics for the correlated data have a much bigger spread, so much more often than they should be they give a significant result (note that the null hypothesis is true in this simulation). So we don't have the significance level we asked for -- if we thought we had a type I error rate of around 5%, it would actually be about 69% in this simulation.

[image]

Comment: I'm slowly working through your answer to try and finally nail my understanding of the dependence problem. Let's say we carry out a t-test. We have a dependent variable (DV) measured on two groups (group1 and group2). Assume their is dependence within both group1 and group2. How does your X and Y correspond to DV, group1 and group2?

Comment: The only place I use X and Y in my answer is when presenting the rules for working out a variance of a sum. That comes into the variance of the within-group mean, of course. You can either apply the rules for two random variables I gave there recursively (first two observations, that added to the third, and so on), or use the $n$ observation equivalents [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables). You don't specify the directions and sizes of the dependence so it's hard to be specific.

Comment: could you describe $p(X_t, X_{t-1}) = 0.9$ in words please?

Comment: "The correlation of the $t$-th observation with the previous one is $0.9$". This (correlation between adjacent observations) would be something you might see with data collected over time or along some spatial dimension.